# use css to insert background image in navbar link with

Tags: html, image, css

For some reason the image won't appear in the navbar, if I add borders to the css or any styling it appears but not the image. If I add the image explicitly in the html using the `<img/>` tag it appears but the `hover` over won't work..

CSS

```
<style>
     nav{
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        height:35px;
        text-align:center;
        border-top:1px solid #464140;
        border-bottom:1px solid #464140;
        padding-top:3px;
    }

    .img1{
        border-radius:4px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_a-PcgaUqYBJgn0JywzAQot-30Hl4tyODvxTj4F91pTbWE7fZ');
     }

     .img1:hover{
        border-radius:4px;
        background-image:url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTbV-LxTpyrvTdSdHF5ulyzUJoe12f6nQr8Gn3hM3TjUfZNiEc');
     }
</style>
```

HTML

```
 <body>
     <nav> 
         <a  href = "index.html" class = "img1" title = "HOME"> </a> 
     </nav>
 </body>
```

Comment: Put your code in the fiddle please

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle.net demo?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/JuiceJay/bjy7v902/4/

Here it is.. I cant get one image to work but not multiple.. I'm also having problems with the vertical align and retaining original image sizes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DEMO:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/UGuTJdmvDMCgLSmJ5PfZ?p=preview

**For multiple images menu:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/IFuiYBVcGkERgMSOfsZO?p=preview

Add `display:block` property to the anchor tag. Anchor tags are inline elements by default and thus have no width and height.

```css
 nav{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height:35px;
    text-align:center;
    border-top:1px solid #464140;
    border-bottom:1px solid #464140;
    padding-top:3px;
}

.img1{
    border-radius:4px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR_a-PcgaUqYBJgn0JywzAQot-30Hl4tyODvxTj4F91pTbWE7fZ');
    display: block;
 }

 .img1:hover{
    border-radius:4px;
    background-image:url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTbV-LxTpyrvTdSdHF5ulyzUJoe12f6nQr8Gn3hM3TjUfZNiEc');
 }





<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
 <nav> 
     <a  href = "index.html" class = "img1" title = "HOME"> </a> 
 </nav>
```

Comment: thanks, i can get one picture to work but not multiple pictures. Take a look at my fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/JuiceJay/bjy7v902/4/

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/IFuiYBVcGkERgMSOfsZO?p=preview . Please check the demo here. I guess that's what you need

Comment: this is exactly what i need haha.. can you please advice me on how to get an  equal spacing between each of the images..

Comment: I didn't get your question. What do you mean by equal spacing? I guess you want some margin. Right now there is not space at all. If you want some space then you can add margins to each li item.

Answer (score 3):

It's beacuse following tag is empty:

```
<a  href = "index.html" class = "img1" title = "HOME"> </a>
```

Add `display:block;` to your img1 class

Comment: sorry i did not add the sources to online images. just did.. but the sources in my code are good.. they are working elsewhere

Comment: it did work thanks.. what if i wanted to add more photos to the navbar, wouldn't i have to use inline, can you give me in idea on how to do this?

Comment: Put them in ul list with list-style-type: none;

Comment: I can't give you solution on a plate. Read this for starters: http://css-snippets.com/simple-horizontal-navigation/

Answer (score 3):

Add `display: block` to the `a` tag - this happens as the `a` is `display: inline` by default and goes to *zero* `width` and *zero* `height` if there is no content inside:

```css
nav {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #464140;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #464140;
  padding-top: 3px;
}
.img1 {
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.img1:hover {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/200x200');
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <a href="index.html" class="img1" title="HOME"></a>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: what if i wanted to add more photos to the navbar, wouldn't i have to use inline, can you give me in idea on how to do this?